# Django Building A Restful API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to build a Django Api App that allows me to render multiple variations of data. For example take a look at my code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'nav-func$', views.FundNavApi.as_view(option='nav_func')),
    url(r'fund_nav/(?P<fund_id>[0-9]+)$', views.FundNavApi.as_view(option='fund_nav'))
]
```

Views.py

```
class FundNavApi(APIView):
    option = 'default'
    model_class = NAV
    fund_id = None

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        if self.option == 'nav_func':
            res = self.nav_func
            print(res)
        elif self.option == 'fund_nav':
            print(self.kwargs['fund_id'])
        return Response("Hi")

    @staticmethod
    def nav_func():
        querysets = NAV.objects.filter(fund__account_class=0, transmission=3).values(
        'valuation_period_end_date').annotate(
        total_nav=Sum(F('outstanding_shares_par') * F('nav'))).order_by('valuation_period_end_date')

        df = read_frame(querysets, coerce_float=True)
        df.loc[:, 'valuation_period_end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.valuation_period_end_date)
        df.loc[:, 'timestamp'] = df.valuation_period_end_date.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 6
        df.loc[:, 'total_nav'] = df.total_nav
        df = df.round(0)
        print(df[['timestamp', 'total_nav']].values.tolist())
        return df[['timestamp', 'total_nav']].values.tolist()
```

As you can see, I want to use the same `model` but manipulate the data differently based on the `url`. So, I use the `option=''` parameter as a way to tell the `controller` what to render. So I have two questions:

1. Is this the correct approach? Like is this what professionals do in terms of building an API that renders different variations of data while using one type of model?

Answer (score 0):

Sinc your title indicates you want to create a RESTfull api you should pbly use django-rest-framework with django to ease the RESTfull part of your api design a little bit.

DRF has a great tutorial and you should work it through because an 'professional' api with responses in multiple responses is not a beginners challange.
Thankfully DRF has you covered because it comes with some defauls so called Renderers. A Renderer is basically responsible for the format your data is beeing presented e.g. html, json etc. In addition DRF can handle custom Renderers so you can easly extend it to your needs.

If you want to get a headstart in overall RESTfull API design I recommend the book, author and community of https://apisyouwonthate.com/. Author & Community = great guys + the book gets you up to speed in no time (I have no affiliation to the author, just think the book is great for an introduction to REST).